# Properties of schemes determined by field valued points

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, schemes

Are there any interesting cases (interesting here is interpreted rather loosely here) where you can show $X$ has property $P$ whenever all $X(K)$ have property $P$ where $K$ runs through all fields?

To clarify, let me state different versions of the questions.

Assume $X$ is defined over a base field $k$ and $K$ runs through all field extensions of $k$.

**Version 1**
Consider the sets $X(K)$ as having just a topology and assume $X$ is reduced.

I'm concerned with topological properties: being irreducible, being connected, counting irreducible or connected components, being an open subscheme of another scheme, being non empty,...

**Version 1'**
If $X$ is not necessarily reduced what properties are insensitive to being reduced or not?

**Version 2**
Consider $X(K)$ as a topological space with the additional data of a sheaf of rings where for every $U(K) \subset X(K)$ we consider the ring generated by set maps $r_K: U(K) \to K$ for $r \in \mathcal{O}_X(U)$ where $r_K$ is defined by setting $r_K(\phi) = \phi^\#(r)$ for every $\phi \in U(K)$.

I'm more interested in Version 1 but perhaps more can be said about Version 2.

Motivation:
Sometimes the field valued points of a scheme are much easier to understand than general $R$ points. For example a split reductive group $G$ you have the Bruhat decomposition of $G(K)$ which tell you the double cosets for a Borel $B \subset G$ are indexed by permutation matrices. But in general the cosets in $G(R)$ for a $K$-alebra $R$ are more complicated.

Comment: If X is a scheme, then the field valued points cannot distinguish between X and red X, the underlying reduced subscheme.

Comment: X(K) is just a set so not clear what properties it has. Do you want to work with properties of the functor $X(K)$?

Comment: @DanielBarter, so maybe the question makes more sense if one stipulates that the scheme is reduced?  In that case, for example, is there any sense in which we know 'everything' about the scheme once we know its functor of field points?

Comment: @WillSawin, the post mentions the example of reductive groups.  Maybe one more generally wants to understand $X$ in terms of *additional structure* on $X(K)$—for example, group structure, or, if $K$ is a special field (say, $p$-adic or Archimedean), topology?

Comment: @solbap. One example you probably already know. If $X_{/\mathbf{C}}$ is proper, then the analytic space $X(\mathbf{C})$ "knows" $X$ by GAGA theorems.

Comment: A "rational homomorphism" between smooth groups of finite type over a field $k$ always arises from an actual $k$-homomorphism (by suitable translation considerations over $k_s$), so by considering points valued in function fields of connected components over a large finite Galois extension of $k$ we see that a smooth $k$-group $G$ of finite type is determined by the associated group-valued functor on the category of separable (not necessarily algebraic) extension fields of $k$. But this is extremely special to the case of such $k$-groups. The question would benefit from better motivation.

Comment: @WillSawin I have made edits to state the question more precisely. Mostly I want to consider $X(K)$ as just a topological space. Is there other structure of $X(K)$ from a functorial point of view that come to mind?

Comment: I have edited the question to address the comments thus far. Is the phrasing still problematic? Can it be considered for re-opening?